# Remove value in circle Swiftcharts

Tags: swift, swiftcharts

At the momtent I try to find out how I can make the table that I would need for my app. I would like to remove the value in the circles.

[image]

But now I came across the possibility during my search that it is possible to hide the value in the circle.

This should be possible with `LineChartData.drawValuesEnabled = false`. However, I can not find the same in the Swiftcharts code, so I wonder if this option has been removed or is it called / works differently?

Answer (score 0):

Values should be removed from DataSet, not from LineChartData.
This code might help you.

```
 let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: values)
    
 set1.drawValuesEnabled = false
```